# OpenVPN - Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [CMD-LINE]:1: inactif (2.4.7)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have an issue setting up OpenVPN in portainer (docker-transmission-openvpn), I think the automatic modification is adding the "inactif" line 1 in the config file ?
I tried FTP (FileZilla) and look after the modified config file with no success (can't find it).

Any help is appreciated I have been blocked by this for hours..

Thanks

Full error :

```
Starting container with revision: a95f586492b2b7e8ff2cc8ac7f91bc43c0cccc40
Creating TUN device /dev/net/tun 
Using OpenVPN provider: UNLIMITED
Running with VPN_CONFIG_SOURCE auto
No bundled config script found for UNLIMITED. Defaulting to external configFound configs for UNLIMITED in /tmp/tmp.D9wZbHUftB/vpn-configs-contrib-main/openvpn/unlimited, will replace current content in /etc/openvpn/unlimited
Downloading configs from https://github.com/username/vpn-configs-contrib/archive/main.zip into /tmp/tmp.U5sJuVJUSJ
Extracting configs to /tmp/tmp.D9wZbHUftB
Cleanup: deleting /tmp/tmp.U5sJuVJUSJ and /tmp/tmp.D9wZbHUftB
Starting OpenVPN using config fr.ovpn
Modifying /etc/openvpn/unlimited/fr.ovpn for best behaviour in this container
Modification: Point auth-user-pass option to the username/password file
Modification: Change ca certificate path
Modification: Change ping options
Modification: Update/set resolv-retry to 15 seconds
Modification: Change tls-crypt keyfile path
Modification: Set output verbosity to 3
Modification: Remap SIGUSR1 signal to SIGTERM, avoid OpenVPN restart loop
Found existing OPENVPN credentials at /config/openvpn-credentials.txt
adding route to local network 192.168.1.0/24 via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [CMD-LINE]:1: inactif (2.4.7)
```

Config File (Hid sensitive info):

```
client
dev tun
reneg-sec 0
persist-tun
persist-key
ping 5
ping-exit 30
nobind
comp-lzo no
remote-random
remote-cert-tls server
auth-nocache
route-metric 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth sha512
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEjjCCA/egAwIBAgIJAKsVbHBdakXuMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIHgMQswCQYD
***********
DbKH5RTMHHe8FkSxh6Zz/BMN
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFVTCCBL6gAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB4DELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
***********
IuLkOfU5ZxbVmEg/nOsnSctsIxfVwukk7g==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCgwIBXgG1BjH8L
***********
srSVZZZEaWJxokFEDsW5oNp9
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

</key>
remote fr.vpnunlimitedapp.com
proto udp
```

Comment: Maybe **inactive** had been misspelled as **inactif**, based on the error message.  A search for text in the files should find it.

Comment: Inactif is the french word for inactive, I don't think I have any saying on this, maybe change my language to english so it's generated in english ? I'll try that and report back.
edit: it's already in english ._.